# Downloading multiple similar URLs using braces

Tags: shell-script, wget

```
#!/bin/sh
orig=$1

var=${orig%.jpg}
var=`echo "$var" | grep -o "[0-9][0-9]$"`

cutten=${orig%[0-9][0-9].jpg}

sequence='{1,'
for i in `seq 2 $(( $var - 1 ))`; do
sequence=$sequence$i","
done
output=$cutten$sequence$var"}.jpg"

echo "$output"
#wget "$output"
```

It takes an img link, eg: `http://foo.bar/some-image-20.jpg` and returns 
`http://foo.bar/some-image-{1,2,3,4,5,…,18,19,20}.jpg`,
that is, files *1.jpg through *20.jpg

While on echo it works as expected (the output is as above) when run with wget:

```
-- (Date/Time) -- http://foo.bar/some-image-%7B1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20%7D.jpg
(Proceeds to resolve this whole one link, and fails)
```

Pretty much it replaces '{' with '%7B' and '}' with '%7D'. Any Ideas?

Comment: It's not random, it's url encoding.  `7B` is the hexadecimal number for `{`.  See `man wget`, search for `restrict-file-names`.  The way you describe it, it sounds like you're trying to download one file with 20 numbers in it.  But it seems more likely you're trying to download 20 files each with one number in it?  Please explicitly say what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Mikel I want to achieve the same result as running "wget https://foo.bar/image-{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}.jpg" since wget itself cant use wildcards, only adding the url of the last image "./myscript https://foo.bar/image-7.img"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any web server that supports wildcard downloads, you'll have to fetch each URL individually.

Keeping as much of your original script as possible, that would be something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
orig=$1

var=${orig%.jpg}
var=$(echo "$var" | grep -o "[0-9][0-9]$")

cutten=${orig%[0-9][0-9].jpg}

for i in $(seq 1 $(($var - 1))) ; do
      echo $cutten$i.jpg
done | wget -i -
```

This makes use of wget's `-i` option to read a list of URLs to fetch from a file, in this case stdin, so we can just pipe the list of files to wget.

(if you want to see what it is going to download before you run it, replace `wget -i -` with `cat`)

Comment: You can use {1,2,3,4,5...etc} with wget itsef thats what I though. But anyways since I cant get this thing work this way, after a while I also though about the '-i'  flag and I was ready to use that until I saw your comment, so thanks!

Comment: The wildcard expansion is done by the shell, not by wget...and if the shell doesn't find any matching files in the current directory (which it won't), it will just pass the wildcard as a literal string to wget.

Answer (score 0):

`http://foo.bar/some-image-{1,2,3}.jpg` is bash source syntax to represent the list of words `http://foo.bar/some-image-1.jpg`, `http://foo.bar/some-image-2.jpg`, `http://foo.bar/some-image-3.jpg`. Source syntax means that it's something you type in your script, it isn't something that happens on a variable expansion. `echo "$output"` shows you the command you'll be running, which is

```
wget http://foo.bar/some-image-{1,2,3}.jpg
```

Since braces are not valid in URLs, `wget` [encodes them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) as `%7B` and `%7D`. This is unrelated to your problem: the server just sees one URL containing what is as far as it's concerned an URL that doesn't refer to an existing file.

You need to pass 3 (in my example, 20 in yours) different URLs on the command line of wget. You could use `eval` to make bash parse the content of a variable as source code to make use of its brace expansion feature, but it would be easier to build the list in the first place — this isn't any more difficult than building the string with the braces.

```
#!/bin/sh
suffix=${1##*[0-9]}
prefix=${1%"$suffix"}
last=${prefix##*[!0-9]}
prefix=${prefix%"$last"}

while [ "$last" -gt 1 ]; do
  last=$((last-1))
  set -- "$prefix$last$suffix" "$@"
done

wget "$@"
```